# How to get the process id of adobe when it is running in my MFC project?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, activex

I create a MFC project, this MFC project hosts an Adobe ActiveX control.

When I start my MFC project, the adobe active control will launched the Adobe process under it.
[image]
This is my task manager under windows 10, you can clearly see that Adobe process is launched by my project.
But how can I get the process id of the Adobe process which is launched by my project ?

I am using the adobe active x control sample code from this link :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9537/Adobe-ActiveX-Control-with-MFC

class CAcroAXDocShim
The reason why I need to get the pid is that I need to capture the mouse event over the pdf when it is displayed in active x control.
If I use the following function:

```
LowLevelMouseProc callback function
```

I need to pass the process id of adobe into it. If I passed 0 as the id, then it will capture all mouse input event for whole system.

Comment: Why do you need the PID?

Comment: I want to control over the adobe process when it is displaying the pdf in active x control. For example, when the user right click the pdf in active x control, I can receive the event by the process id

Comment: @beasone `LowLevelMouseProc` is a hook callback for `SetWindowsHookEx()`, which takes a **thread ID**, not a **process ID**.  In any case, your ActiveX control is embedded in the Adobe process, so look at things like `GetCurrentProcessId()` and `GetCurrentThreadId()`